# How to call an asyncTask to an outside service from within a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

"I'm trying to make a call to an outside service via an asyncTask in another class from with a fragment. My IDE is telling me it cannot execute the method getInstance from my Fragment. However I go about it, I ultimately need to invoke the doInBackground() method of the Async ClarafaiPutImagesInModel class.

I have tried making my surrounding class a singleton, but am either doing so incorrectly or that's not the way to  solves the problem.

This is the method in the fragment:

```
  private void endOfTutorial(ResponseViewModel viewModel, View view) {
    Snackbar snackbarNo12 = Snackbar
        .make(view, getString(R.string.tutorial_no12), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbarNo12.show();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      if (malingeringCount > 2) {
        Snackbar snackbarNo13 = Snackbar
            .make(view, getString(R.string.tutorial_no13), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbarNo13.show();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        tutorialPosition = 0;
      } else {
        Snackbar snackbarNo14 = Snackbar
            .make(view, getString(R.string.tutorial_no14), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbarNo14.show();
        sandwich.setHumanEat(false);
        viewModel.updateHumanEat(sandwich);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.saved_tutorial_complete_key), true);
        editor.apply();
        tutorialPosition++;
        viewModel.pruneTutorial();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        LiveData<List<Sandwich>> feedClarafi = viewModel.getSandwichForModel();
        ClarafaiService.ClarifaiPutImagesInModel modelMaker = new ClarafaiService.getInstance().ClarifaiPutImagesInModel();
        modelMaker.execute(feedClarafi);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
      System.out.println(exc);
    }
    Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        .navigate(R.id.action_responseFragment_to_sandwichImageFragment);
  }
```

And this is the Class in question:

```
public class ClarafaiService {


  private static final double CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.50;
  private String modelId;
  private boolean trained;
  private String modelVersionId;
  private static ClarafaiService SOLEINSTANCE;


  final ClarifaiClient client = new ClarifaiBuilder("APIKEY")
      .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor())
          .build()
      )
      .buildSync();

  private ClarafaiService(){}

  public static ClarafaiService getInstance(){
    if(SOLEINSTANCE == null){
      SOLEINSTANCE = new ClarafaiService();
    }
    return SOLEINSTANCE;
  }





  public class ClarifaiPutImagesInModel extends
      AsyncTask<Sandwich, Void, ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiInput>>> {


    @Override
    protected ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiInput>> doInBackground(Sandwich... sandwiches) {
      List<ClarifaiInput> inputs = new LinkedList<ClarifaiInput>();
      for (Sandwich sandwich : sandwiches) {
        ClarifaiInput input = ClarifaiInput.forImage(sandwich.getFileName())
            .withConcepts(Concept.forID("sandwich"));
        inputs.add(input);
      }
      return client.addInputs()
          .plus(inputs)
          .executeSync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiInput>> response) {
      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        new ClarafaiCreateModel().execute();
      } else {
       //TODO figure out how to show a snackbar/toast without reference to a view
      }
    }
  }

//There are more classes below this but they are moot if I can't call this first one.
```

I would expect to get a response back from Clarafai that my images were sucessfully input, but am instead being told that it cannt call the method  getInstance().

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Apologies, actual solution is to add the `static` keyword to `ClarifaiPutImagesInModel` like so:

`public static class ClarifaiPutImagesInModel extends
      AsyncTask<Sandwich, Void, ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiInput>>> {`

---

Your issue in attempting to initialize your `ClarifaiPutImagesInModel` is that you do not need to call `getInstance` on your service. in calling `getInstance` you are attempting to create a new `ClarifaiPutImagesInModel` through an instance of the service class.

This line:

`ClarafaiService.ClarifaiPutImagesInModel modelMaker = new ClarafaiService.getInstance().ClarifaiPutImagesInModel();`

Instead:

`ClarafaiService.ClarifaiPutImagesInModel modelMaker = new ClarafaiService.ClarifaiPutImagesInModel();`

As an aside, I would encourage you to explore Android and Java conventions further, `AsyncTask` is an antiquated API for asynchronous work, and there are lots of new 1st party Android tools as well as 3rd party libraries to accomplish asynchronous work in a cleaner and less error prone way.

Comment: Thanks, Eli. I look forward to expanding my tool set. However when I call ClarafaiService.ClarifaiPutImagesInModel modelMaker = new ClarafaiService.ClarifaiPutImagesInModel(); I get the error: package.ClarafaiService is not an enclosing class.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an edit. It appears you have some misunderstandings about how Java class/file structure works, I would encourage you to read some basic java tutorials regarding this, as that would help you immensely.

Comment: Thank you again, Eli. However the closing brace for the ClarifaiService class is on line 192, not included in my post, and it does in fact include all subsequent nested classes. I will tr breaking up the service class.

Comment: Are you referring to the private ClarifaiService constructor? Are you suggested I enclose all nested classes in that?

Comment: Apologies, wrong direction (although it would work) You need to add the `static` keyword to the declaration of the ImagesInModel class.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate the dialogue. Will have to make further changes to the Service calls to accommodate the static change (static fields etc), but appreciate the help very much.  BAM! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: You can make the class declaration static without changing anything else about the class, and it will still work. Here is some reading on nested classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html